# How to read json response as name value pairs in JQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I want to read `json` response as name and value pairs in my `JQuery` code. Here is my sample JSON response that I return from my dotnet code:

```
const string format = "\"HasCases\": \"{0}\""; 
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(128); 
json.Append("{"); 
json.AppendFormat(format, JSONString("true"));
json.Append("}"); 
Response.Clear(); 
Response.AppendHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");                                                                               Response.Write(json.ToString()); 
Response.End();
```

To get Json value ,is it necessary to use Response code?In my Json page , I am able to get the output as HasCases : true.

Here is my JQuery code

```
<span id="testSpan" runat="server">inactive</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
inactive 
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: "~/Pages/UserCaselistnonEmptyAjax.aspx", 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (response){
        $('#testSpan').innerHTML = response.HasCases; 
       }, 
     error: function (e1, e2, e3) {
  $('#testSpan').innerHTML = 'Error';
      }
   });
 </Script>
```

When I am debugging form `firebug` My control does not going to `"$('#testSpan').innerHTML = response.HasCases; "`.It is coming out from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects don't implement `.innerHTML`. Use `.html()` instead:

```
$('#testSpan').html(response.HasCases);
```

Comment: yes you are correct but the control doesn't going to success or error methods.I changed the code to   $('#testSpan').html(response.HasCases);

Answer (score 0):

I am returning my json using

```
return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(request));
```

in my c# code.and I am calling the function returning this value at page load event.
and the output is this

```
{"registration_ids":["1","2"],"data":{"message":"Your message","tickerText":"Your ticker","contentTitle":"Your content"}}
```

but I am unable to read this returned json fomrat with jquery ajax
my ajax is below

```
function as()
  {

                $.ajax({
                      type:"get",
                      url:"mydjson.aspx",
                      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 
                      dataType: {'json':'datas'}, 
                      //data: JSON.stringify(request),//{ get_param: 'value' },
                      success:function (msg) {

                                         $("#table").html("<h1>" + msg+ "</h1>").fadeIn("slow");

                                    },
                                      //  function (data, status)

                     error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) 
                            {
                               var errorMessage = error || xhr.statusText;

                                $("#table").html("<h3>" + errorMessage + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
                            }
                   });
        return false;
   //   });
```

}

I am getting the error "Ivalid json" plus the content of page" mydjson.aspx".help me for this.